# How can I block many lines of code in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

Hive sql - Is there a way to block out thousands of lines of code without having to put dashes at the beginning of every line?

Comment: Did you try ctrl + /?

Comment: I'm not running interactively. So I'm not sure how to use that,

Answer (score 0):

Right now. It doesn't appear so. It is listed as a pending improvement for a future version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19692